# pure-ftpd debian, can't get www-data user working

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ftp, www-data, pureftpd

I'm trying to add FTP access to the Apache web files, in the past I have done this with an `ftpuser` and group arrangement. This time I would like to make it possible to login directly as `www-data` (the default Apache user on Debian) to make things a bit cleaner.

I have checked and re-checked all the common issues;

- MinUID is set to 1 (`www-data` has uid 33)
- `www-data` has shell set to `/bin/bash` in `/etc/passwd`
- PAMAuthentication is off
- UnixAuthentication is on
- I have restarted pure-ftpd using `/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart`

My resulting pure-ftpd run is;

```
/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l unix -A -Y 1 -u 1 -E -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -8 UTF-8 -B
```

My syslog contains;

> Oct  7 19:46:40 Debian-60-squeeze-64 pure-ftpd: (?@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
>   [WARNING] Can't login as [www-data]: account disabled

And my ftp client is giving me;

> 530 Sorry, but I can't trust you

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You answered your own question, which is good. But another suggestion I have—to achieve your larger goal—is to create a common `www-group` that would be accessible by Apache & others. The trick is to adjust `/etc/apache2/envvars` so Apache creates files that are group writable by adding `umask 002` to the bottom of that file and then changing `export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-readwrite` to be `export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-group`.  Then you can assign other users to that `www-group` and even make `www-group` a user’s default group.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian *squeeze*, if you have installed pure-ftpd from the repos, the `init.d` script appears to be bugged:

```
/etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
```

Results in syslog containing;

```
pure-ftpd: (?@?) [ERROR] Unable to start a standalone server: [Address already in use]
```

And a peek with `netstat -ltpn` clearly shows that pure-ftpd continues to run, that is to say `restart` does not attempt to stop the server, it merely attempts to run a new instance, and fails.

The solution is to *kill* the pre-ftpd process. And then start it again with `init.d` (or manually as with the example run code in the OP.

Comment: I discovered this solution while I was halfway through posting the question. It might seem a little off as an answer, but it was my issue nevertheless, and I thought someone in the future might just benefit (I have been googling for hours).